# Open form if page in webBrowser contains string

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm quite new to C# and I'm working on a form that logs into a website, navigates to a specific page and then it should check if that page contains the words "Registered Plus" (This all in a webBrowser) Now I got this all working, except for the last part. I have been thinking and searching for hours about how to make my application check if the current webpage contains "Registered Plus"... This is my code for the button so far:

```
    private void btnReboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("username")[0].SetAttribute("value", usernameBox.Text);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password")[0].SetAttribute("value", passwordBox.Text);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("submit")[0].InvokeMember("click");
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://website.com/login.php?action=login");

    }
```

Does anyone know how to make it check if this page: http://website.com/login.php?action=login contains "Registered Plus" ? Or maybe  a tutorial about how to do something similar to this? Thanks alot in advance. Have been stuck on this part for quite a while now..

UPDATE:

Got a comment telling me about DocumentText.Contains, tried this:

```
    private void btnReboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("username")[0].SetAttribute("value", usernameBox.Text);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password")[0].SetAttribute("value", passwordBox.Text);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("submit")[0].InvokeMember("click");
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://darkbox.nl/usercp.php?action=usergroups");
        if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Registered Plus"))
        {
            label3.Text = "You're plus";
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "You're not plus";
        }
    }
```

However it still tells me "You're not plus"

Am I doing it right this way? Or..

Comment: Can you deserialize the Document XML into a string and search that string?

Comment: Do you mean checking the entire HTML of the web page for the text "Registered Plus" ?

Comment: can't you just do `webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Registered Plus")` [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Gunther34567 Updated my question with the results of that. I think I'm at least getting closer :) Thanks

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes that's what I was trying to do indeed. Probably not really the best way to do it, but it's a start.. :P

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also, from the code example, it looks like you are trying to do a login, but immediately after submitting, you are telling the web browser to navigate away from the page in the Navigate method. This means that, whatever the server responds as a result of that login attempt(including cookie) will be lost and you probably wont be able to actually get the page you are requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to test the code right now, but the big issue is that the call to the webBrowser1.Navigate is executed asynchroniously. Just like when you request it in IE or Chrome, it takes anywhere from a second to a minute for the page to load (or give an error.) On the other hand, your C# code takes barely a millisecond to move from the Navigate request to the next line of code.

You need to fire off your code checking the Document once the Navigate() method returns an event indicating it is done.

```
    private bool shouldEvaluateReponse = false;

    private void btnReboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("username")[0].SetAttribute("value", usernameBox.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password")[0].SetAttribute("value", passwordBox.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("submit")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            shouldEvaluateResponse = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://darkbox.nl/usercp.php?action=usergroups");
    }

    public void WebBrowser1_Navigated(object sender,  WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
       //ignore this method if the flag isn't set.
       if (!shouldEvaluateResponse) return; 

       //reset the flag so this method doesn't keep executing
       shouldEvaluateResponse = false;

       if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Registered Plus"))
       {
                label3.Text = "You're plus";
       }
       else
       {
                label3.Text = "You're not plus";
       }
    }
```

Comment: That looks like it should work lol, but using this 'label3' doesn't change at all. I think that's because I forgot something, but I don't know what..

Comment: You also need to make sure that the webBrowser is wired up to the Navigated method. If you are using the Form Design, you can get to the Navigated event in the control's property grid. If you are manually instantiating the control, then you can use webBrowser1.Navigated += WebBrowser1_Navigated; (I believe I have that syntax right, but trust your IDE over my memory. Its been a long week.)

Comment: Yea that's what I forgot to do.. I'll try to figure out how to do it through that property grid. (Yea, I have to figure that out.. That's how new I am to this, I guess)

Comment: Oh @Goblyn27 I did that now. But right when I start debugging it changes label3 to "You're not plus" because it navigates to /index.php right away, there you log in, then it navigates to some other page, and then it navigates to this webBrowser1.Navigate("http://darkbox.nl/usercp.php?action=usergroups");

Right now it isn't that much of a problem, but when opening a form instead of updating a label's text, it is.. It will open the form each time the application navigates.

Besides that, thank you SO much, the check itself works now! Really appreciate all your help :D

Comment: @DBMika that is because the Navigated event will be triggered for every document loaded into the web browser. You will want to include in your class a method to determine when it should and should not execute the the Nvaigated code. I will do a quick edit to explain.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. Managed to do it now. I suddenly came across a new problem though. Before I went to bed the logging into the website worked fine.. Now when I woke up I made a few really minor changes to my program and now when I try to log in on the website by simulating the click on the login button on the website, it's gonna tell me my password is wrong. When I manually click it in the browser, it logs in fine... Any idea what this could be? Or should I make a new question about this problem.